# Undo PHP's parsing of $_POST multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, post, multidimensional-array

If the request contains a field named `x[y]`, PHP's resultant `$_POST` array looks like the following:

```
array (
    'x' => array (
        'y' => ''
    )
)
```

Is there anyway I can stop this multidimensional array parsing and just have an array:

```
array (
    'x[y]' => ''
)
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: you'd probably have to encode the `[]` as %5B and %5D in the form so they won't be seen as array key references.

Comment: Is that naming convention required? Can you not use a name like `x_y`?

Comment: I've passed multidimensional arrays be serializing and encoding them.  Another option would be to use `$_SESSION` storage if the form that is being posted from is on your server

Comment: @PatrickQ: I don't have control over the field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because it's the browser that sends values as a POST array, but you can undo it with a little manipulation if you absolutely need to name things that way...

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $_POST[$key.'['.$k.']'] = $v;
        }
        unset($_POST[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the browser doesn't send it as an array, the browser sends it as a simple query string. PHP parses it into this structure. I guess this is the simplest solution, although I'd throw it in a function so it can be recursive....

Thanks.